# Is there a native inline-block HTML 'container' element?

Tags: html, xhtml

A `span` is an `inline` element and `div` is a `block` element. Is there a 'native' (X)HTML / HTML5 `inline-block` element that can act like a container? (Without applying CSS)

Definitions:

> **block** 
> This value causes an element to generate a block box.
>   **inline-block**
>  This value causes an element to generate an inline-level
>   block container. The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block
>   box, and the element itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level
>   box. 
> **inline**
> This value causes an element to generate one or more
>   inline boxes.

Comment: @Oded: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop

Comment: An image is `inline-block`, it will not break in a line.

Comment: Hm, guess you are right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402761/img-elements-block-level-element-or-inline-element. Quote: In CSS, you can set an element to display: `inline-block` to make it replicate the behaviour of images --> So you there's your answer as well. You need to specify it.

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker, @ErikDekker: The specs say nothing of this. HTML5 specifies `img` as Flow content, which kind of implies and `inline` display mode. It seems that [none of the browsers](http://meiert.com/en/blog/20070922/user-agent-style-sheets/) actively apply `inline-block` to `<img>` elements, either (which given that the default is `inline`, see CSS2 spec, implies that images are indeed `inline`, not `inline-block`). Saying that `inline-block` "replicates the behavior of images" is kind of an over-simplification IMHO.

Comment: Is there still not an inline block element in 2019?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, there is not. You have to specify `inline-block` explictly.

Answer (score 10):

Strictly speaking `<button>` fulfils the criteria set. [HTML5 says](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/rendering.html#the-button-element-0)

> When the button binding applies to a button element [which it ordinarily does], the element is
>   expected to render as an 'inline-block' box rendered as a button whose
>   contents are the contents of the element.

However while it is a container element that has a default inline-block rendering, it is not a **General Purpose** container so can't be used for anything but as a button.

Answer (score 1):

`iframe` is also inline-block too

Comment: Link to any documentation about this?

Comment: Nope, it's an inline replaced element.  Tends to work about the same as inline-block, but technically, it isn't.