# Border-radius and padding not playing nice

Tags: image, padding, css

I'm having trouble trying to get a radius on images. I've simplified my problem and exaggerated the variables for demonstration purposes.

**CSS**:

```css
div.wrap img {
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
         border-radius: 50px;
}
img.pic {
    padding: 15px 25px 35px 45px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img class="pic" src="http://i.imgur.com/UAef0.jpg"
         width="300" height="300" />
</div>
```

If I remove the padding, poof, pretty corners.
If it helps, there's a reason why they're in two different classes. "wrap" can have more than one "pic" in it. Sometimes they'll be of the same class, other times they wont, sort like this:

```css
img.left_pic  { float:left;  padding:5px 10px 5px 5px; }
img.right_pic { float:right; padding:5px 5px 5px 10px; }
```

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NwfW6/

**Edited for a solution:**

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/NwfW6/29/) was more or less what I basically was trying to do. I think I was having a 'duh' moment. I'm sure now the declaration I needed to used was **margin** *not* **padding**. Another Thanx to GGJ for reminding me how to go about it the right way. And what Jan said about adding padding to an 'img' tag making no sense, It doesn't. My bad.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your border radius will be outside of the padding, try setting margins instead which will space outside of the border.

Answer (score 10):

Set the padding on "wrap" not on the image (setting paddings on images does not make much sense :)), that should fix your problem.

Comment: Sorta would work, but the "wrap" element wasn't just around the "pic" element, maybe I worded it funny. Anyways putting an actual wrap around the pic seems to work, but is not quite practical in my case. thanx though.

Answer (score 4):

This is a byproduct of applying both padding and a border-radius to the same element in some browsers (mostly IE and safari). The border-radius changes the curvature of the border component of the box model, which surrounds the padding component.

In addition to the other answers, another interesting thing that seems to fix the issue is *adding a border line*.   If you don't want to see the border, you could use `border: 1px solid transparent`, like this:

```css
.invisible-border {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

#### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/NET9c/)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with a `span` instead of an `img`. Not exactly the same scenario since both tags have different `display` values (see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402761/is-img-element-block-level-or-inline-level)).

In my case, setting `display:inline-block` to the `span` fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

Late but somehow found the solution for it. you cannot make a circle using it but you can make use of it by making a slight radius below is an example of my solution.

**I need 10px padding and 5px radius for my image, added together border-radius:15px worked fine for me**

I Hope the explanation was a bit better.