# The clickable area for my link is too large

Tags: html, css

I have an `<img>` logo that is wrapped inside a link, and the link is wrapped in a `<div>`.

My code below results in the clickable area for my link to extend 100% horizontally to both edges of the viewport.

How can I make the clickable area for my link to be the size of my logo?

- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLbo6mjr/2/)

My HTML:

```
<div id="logo-container">
    <div id="logo">
    <a href="dashboard.php"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#logo-container{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    background:#ECECEA;
}

#logo{
    margin:0 auto;
    height:auto;
}

#logo img {
    display:block;
    margin:6px auto 10px auto;
}

#logo img{
    width:330px;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Here's some more suggestions for displaying your logo in HTML+CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125335/what-is-the-proper-way-to-display-a-logo-with-css

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is cause image is set to `display: block;`, such expands it to the full available width, pushing the `A` element boundaries to the extreme.

Instead, keep the logo image `inline` and use `text-align:center;` for the `#logo` parent: http://jsfiddle.net/wLbo6mjr/10/

```
#logo{
    text-align:center;
}

#logo img {
    margin:6px 0 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it expanding to the full width of the original container due to the parent lacking a defined width?

Comment: @Frisbetarian the parent `DIV #logo` is a DIV element so a BLOCK-level element. IMG is an inline element, if you set it to display: block will act like it's a (so to say) a DIV element. Being now *block* it'll push the parent `A` element to the extremes available width.

Comment: @misterManSam AFAIK `img` tag is by default an `inline` -level element.

Comment: Its only covering the entire space because its parent div is also a block element with no defined width. Which means that its actually the parent thats covering the entire width and subsequently the image does too by being its child and a block element as well. I wouldn't set a width to an anchor tag with a picture in it. Better is it set the dimensions to the parent div.

Comment: @Frisbetarian take a closer look, the IMG parent is an `A` (inline) element. If you set image to be `display:block` look what happens to the `A`nchor: http://jsbin.com/mevud/1/edit

Comment: @misterManSam what you just showed is a classical behavior for inline elements and a classical cextcontent "issue" where blank space / newline is accounted, if used.

Comment: @misterManSam also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928211/why-does-image-use-display-inline-but-behaves-like-an-inline-block-element

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan And if you remove all the useless styling and just put a width value to logo which is the container of both the anchor tag and the image, all of its children will adjust to its size as opposed to the size of the main container

http://jsbin.com/gowiviruqofa/1/edit

Comment: @misterManSam also read closely: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente

Comment: @Frisbetarian sure... but why??? Why to set a parent width, than you need to set position and margin 0/auto and than you need to etc etc. Let's use CSS and HTML the way it's meant to be used and let's keep it simple.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Setting the width to the parent is a simpler solution than the one you provided as well as being more standards compliant and better practice as opposed to changing the display type of various elements and then settings a width attribute to the image.

Comment: *settings a width attribute to the image* ? You did it! ...with the parent. I removed everything I could.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - I guess [this is why](http://jsbin.com/tefatu/2/edit) I would treat it as an inline-block element, even if technically inline.

Answer (score 4):

Setting a width on logo fixes it

```
#logo{
    width: 330px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wLbo6mjr/8/