# Why does a link overlap the text?

Tags: html, css

This is the HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>
        We bring you the latest in entertainment & information services, right on your phone. From the latest of Bollywood to the futuristic applications, get it all here!
        <a href="#">View All</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS....

```
div{width: 350px;}
a{
    padding: 30px;
    background: red;
    margin: 20px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
    font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I know this could be solved by using `display: inline-block;` in `.a`. But I would like to know why this is overlapping the text? Should it not to go beyond the text?

**[DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/rHCNb/)**

**[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/rHCNb/8/)** now `a` is within a block level of p.

And also have a look at this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rHCNb/5/)**. Img is also an inline element. And why this is not overlapping, this should also be overlapping, right?

Comment: try float:left; or Position:absolute;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<a> tag` is inline level but while `<img> tag` is both inline and block level specially inline-block. So `<a> tag` is overlapping because of inline level which is corresponding to the text but `<img> tag` won't overlap because it is behaving inline-block. And you may know the difference between them.

**Reference:**  [Is <img> element block level or inline level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402761/img-elements-block-level-element-or-inline-element)

An inline element could not be set its width and height and even doesn't work correctly the margin behaviour what actually should do. The margin is applied only to left or right side. Actually this is why, inline element here `<a> tag` would not set its width and height and remain in same line and seems to be overlapped when applied padding values.

The following picture makes you clear to understand about inline vs inline-block

[image: inline-block vs inline]

**[View Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VvbFX/)**

Answer (score 2):

It's overlapping because the default behavior for an `<a>` tag is to fit with the text. If you want it to behave like a block, then set `display: block`.

Answer (score 0):

The initial value for the `display` property on a link is `display: inline`. This means that it will try to fit in with the text and will accept horizontal margins, and padding on all sides, which is exactly why your link overlaps the text. In order for it to accept vertical margins (so it doesn't overlap), you need to set it to `display:block` or `inline-block` if you want it to align with the text still.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below property in **a**.

```
  position:relative;
  float:left;
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rHCNb/2/)

**TIPS:**

1. Write `background-color` instead of the shorthand `background` when you
   are not associating any other property.
2. If you write `display:block` then the block width will be equal to the parent
   width, so always write `width` with `display`.

   ```
   a{
       padding: 30px;
       background-color: red;
       margin: 20px;
       border-radius: 12px;
       color: #fff;
       font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       text-decoration: none;
       display: block;
       width: 50px;
   }
   ```

   [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rHCNb/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Padding doesn't work well with inline elements.

Ref:[Inline Elements and Padding](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/)

Answer (score 0):

This actually is explained in the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting), although it was a bit tricky to find.

> Horizontal margins, borders, and padding are respected between these boxes.

This tacitly implies that vertical margins/borders/padding are *not* respected.  It goes on to say:

> The height of a line box is determined by the rules given in the section on line height calculations

If you move the `<a>` into the contents of the box

```
We bring you the latest in entertainment <a href="#">View All</a>
```

You can see this effect: http://jsfiddle.net/rHCNb/7/ -- the horizontal padding is respected, but not the vertical.  The fact that it covers the other text has to do with [z-indexing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index).