# How is the width of an <svg> determined when margins are involved?

Tags: html, css, svg

It seems like the width of an `<svg>` element is set based on the size of the parent, but *ignoring* margins:

[image]

Why is this? And how can I make an `<svg>` behave like any other `block` element when it comes to sizing?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4p3ww/

Comment: It does exactly the opposite in Firefox…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is no way for some SVG content to say it wants to take up whatever space is available after borders, padding and margins have taken their share (there is no way to create SVG that does NOT have an intrinsic width/height since the 'width' and 'height' attributes default to 100%).

https://wiki.mozilla.org/SVG:Sizing

Seems like there is still a debate on how different browsers should render these, so I'd be careful.  Even with height/width attributes and `max-width` CSS, it still rendered pretty weird for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/4p3ww/3/

Answer (score 2):

Just don't use `<svg>` and `<img>` as if they were block elements. They are not ([Is <img> element block level or inline level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402761/img-elements-block-level-element-or-inline-element)).

If you wrap your `<svg>` into a `<div>` with the `contained` class as per your example, you get results more in line with what you'd expect: http://jsfiddle.net/gLndw/