# Why can input elements be sized if they are inline elements?

Tags: html, css

I was under the impression that inline elements could not have their heights resized, but I am able to do so with `<input type="text"/>` elements.

Am I correct that `<input type="text"/>` elements are inline?

If so, what makes them different from `<span></span>` elements in how they can or cannot be resized.

Comment: Can you share your css where you are not able to apply width to your input tag?

Comment: I was actually confused why I was *able* to set the width of my <input/> elements. Simple answer was that <input/> elements are inline-block not inline. I have accepted JoshC's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An [**`input`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) element is `inline-block` by default, not `inline`.

On the other hand, an element such as a [**`span`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span), is `inline` by default.

The `width`/`height` of an `inline-block` element, such as [**`input`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) can be changed [**(example).**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/zqLLu/)

While an `inline` element, for instance, [**`span`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span), cannot be changed by default, as its dimensions are defined by the "*rendered content within them*". [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/zqLLu/1/).

> This [width] property does not apply to non-replaced inline elements. The content width of a non-replaced inline element's boxes is that of the **rendered content within them** (before any relative offset of children). Recall that inline boxes flow into line boxes. The width of line boxes is given by the their containing block, but may be shorted by the presence of floats. [**- W3 reference**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property)

Comment: Awesome. I had misread somewhere that input elements are inline as opposed to inline-block. Makes perfect sense the behavior I was seeing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They're rendered as inline-block per default. This is why you can specify a width. You can see this in chrome dev tools for example.

http://codepen.io/johannesjo/pen/BrcuE

Comment: Images are not inline-block by default.

Comment: @hugoderhungrige Not by default, they are inline element.

Comment: @hugoderhungrige: No, they are not.

Comment: You're right, but they exactly behave like inline-blocks. You can specify a margin, padding, width and height for images via css, so apart from that they're said to be inline, I can't see much of a difference here. But as this might be missleading I removed it from my answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402761/img-elements-block-level-element-or-inline-element

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `inline` and `inline-block`.

You can change the `height` of the `inline-block` meanwhile you can't change the `inline` elements.

So I think what ever the thing you have changed might be an `inline-block` element.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RZCr7/) for you!