# Why doesn't the margin property effect inline elements?

Tags: css, html, nav

Trying to move some Nav Bar links around within a div, and they are not responding. Can anyone please offer any assistance on this? margin-top seems to be doing nothing. New to CSS.

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    height: 70px;
    vw: 100%;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 83%, .7);
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: -16px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    border-bottom: 1px black solid;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 50%);
    margin-top: 10px;
}

li:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<header>
   <div id="nav">
      <ul>
         <li>About</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <h1>Hi. This is my playground.</h1>
</header>
<div id="me">
   <img src="dp.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: You have a missing `}` in `#nav`.

Comment: Sory the second } is there. Missed it in the copy paste somehow. Adding HTML now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `margin` property doesn't affect `inline` elements, therefore it doesn't work.

> Margin properties specify the width of the margin area of a box. The 'margin' shorthand property sets the margin for all four sides while the other margin properties only set their respective side. These properties apply to all elements, but vertical margins will not have any effect on non-replaced inline elements. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties

Also see [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920253/why-can-input-element-be-sized-if-they-are-inline-elements/19920304#19920304) as to why dimensions cannot be set on `inline` elements.

To solve this, you can either change `li` to `display:inline-block`.  [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/w834D/) - it works.

Alternaetively, you could also float the `li` elements, having the same desired effect. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/w834D/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In the **#nav** you have a typo:

> vw: 100%;

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but vw is an acceptable attribute with CSS3, viewport width?

Comment: vw it's a unit like px, em as far as I know. (ex: width:100vw ) Edit: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths