# how to make a width,height,and background color for a link <a>

Tags: html, css

I've made a widget that contains some categories to be looks like this vertical menu :

[image]

so I've used this way :

```
a {

    width:200px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #836262;
    text-decoration: none 


  }
```

I've written this to change the background color on hover since "category" is the class of the link tag  :

```
.category:hover {

               background-color: #ccc;
               cursor: pointer;


           }
```

but I've failed and the widget appeared :

[image]

why the width and height of the link not 200 and 30 px ??

Comment: you need to apply those styles to a block level element, wrap up the anchors in list elements and hide the list icon with list-style:none

Comment: `a` is an inline element, you need to change its display to either `inline-block` or `block` in order for `height`/`width` to be taken into effect. See this answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920253/why-can-input-element-be-sized-if-they-are-inline-elements/19920304#19920304

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add display: block to the a.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `display: inline-block/block;` for an anchor tag to take in any size styling.

[Here's a quick fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rgRr3/) with your menu, This code is not really for usage it still needs tweaks to be usable.

Answer (score 1):

may be some priorities in css you didn't pay attention about.
to make sure use

```
!important;
```

like this:

```
width:200px !important;
```

!important gives the highest priority.