# Unexpected blank space between div tags

Tags: html, css

I wonder why I'm getting a blank space between two `div` tags. This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="header">
    <img id="background" src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2847/11154210265_a8854fe5c5_h.jpg" alt="background" />
</div>          
<div id="menu">
    Why the above blank space?
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
#background {
max-width:100%;
max-height: 550px;
}
#menu {
background: rgb(170,200,189);
}
```

You can see the behavior here: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ak4D/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the image tag that does that.

Make the image a block element, and it will fix the issue.

```
#background { display: block }
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks. Do you know why is it happening?

Comment: Yup. It's because `<img />` tags are `inline-block` elements. Which means they act like both block and inline elements, in turn meaning that a lot of the default browser CSS for inline elements affects them too. [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402761/img-elements-block-level-element-or-inline-element) explains it quite well.

Answer (score 1):

The initial value for [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) is `baseline`. Therefore, `img` aligns itself at the baseline and leaves a small space below.

Besides the `display: block` @WillemLabu suggested, you have other options to fix this. If you don't have any text, you can set `font-size` on `header`

```
#header {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ak4D/2/)

or adjust `vertical-align` appropriately, of course

```
#background {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ak4D/3/)