# Center images horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 images that i want to center horizontally inside a div,so they need to be centered and next to each other.

here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4" >

            <img class="img-responsive  " src="images/slike/pic1.png" alt=""/>
            <img class="img-responsive   " src="images/slike/pic2.png" alt=""/>

            <img class="img-responsive  " src="images/slike/pic3.png" alt=""/>      

        </div>
    </div>
            </div>
```

When i try center-block class the images are centered but not horizontal but vertical,when i try pull-left or right they are horizontal but not centered.What needs to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your images are sized properly, and can all fit on the same line, try using the following CSS properties:

```
img {
    display:inline-block;
}

.col-xs-4 {
    text-align:center;
}
```

But warning for `inline-block`, all white space between your `img` elements will have to be removed or it will show up as "spaces" between the images.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to apply `text-align:center` to the parent container.

`img` is an [inline-block element by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402761/img-elements-block-level-element-or-inline-element), and will be influenced by the text-align property:

```
.col-xs-4 {
    text-align:center;
}
```

**[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timmah/berX2/)** demonstrating it in action.