# Gap Between Divs - Not Understanding Why It Is There

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a layout to be used on a social website. The site allows CSS/HTML elements. In my design there is a gap between two of my stacked divs. There is no gap in my code so I cannot understand why it is there.

Here is a screenshot: The black space between the header image and menu is the gap.
[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vfErin.css">
</head>
<html>
<body>
<div id="customProfile">
 <div id="customHeader">
  <img src="http://assets.jollyrogerpcs.com/vampirefreaks/axel/cover.png" width="100%">
 </div>
 <div id="customMenu">
  <a href="#">VF Home</a>
  <a href="#">Gallery</a>
  <a href="#">Journal</a>
  <a href="#">Add Me</a>
  <a href="#">Rate & Comment</a>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
/* 
#67C8FF neon-blue 
#83F52C neon-green
*/
* {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   text-decoration: none;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   list-style: none;
   transition: all 0.5s;
}
body {
   background-color: #000;
   text-align: center;
}
#customProfile {
   width: 900px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: left;
   border-left: 1px solid #67C8FF;
   border-right: 1px solid #67C8FF;

}
#customMenu {
   width: 900px;
   font-size: 0pt;
}
#customMenu a:link, #customMenu a:visited {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 20%;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #67c8ff;
   font-size: 14pt;
   height: 30px;
   line-height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell the image to be a block level element like so:

```
img {
    display: block;
}
```

Better yet, give it a class so that you don't style all the images on the page. Because the image is an inline-block element it's subject to line-height, which is what I think is happening here.

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/z91kwzhw/1/

Comment: Odd solution since the img is inside a div which should automatically be a block element if i am not mistaken. Maybe I missed something in my code.

Comment: Instead of a class on the img, you might as well use the context: `#customHeader img { display: block; }`

Comment: You're correct, divs are block elements, but the image is still an inline-block living inside of a block element. It doesn't inherit the block properties of it's parent so you have to force it to be a block.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402761/img-elements-block-level-element-or-inline-element