# How to center logo image using float

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hello I have a logo on my website that I just can't seem to get centered. My css for the logo is as follow,

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #logo {
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 768px;
    }
}
```

http://www.questdesign.com.au/

Any chance you might know what i'm missing? Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try **text-align:center;**

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #logo { float: none; margin: 0 auto; width: 768px; text-align:center; }
}
```

Comment: Have tried text-align:center; but isn't that just for text not images?

Comment: You use the text-align center on the div with id #logo to center all the elements inside it, including images.

Comment: @Endô Fujimoto `img` is actually a text element

Comment: @areim Actually, that's not quite accurate. They're _replaced_ elements. See this [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402761/is-img-element-block-level-or-inline-level)...

Comment: Got it working. Thanks for all your help the code works great

Comment: Sure, no problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 4):

`img` is inline tag, so it will not work even though you add `margin:auto`. Add property `display:block`, it will make img as block level element and `margin:0 auto;` will make it as center.

Your code will be

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #logo { float: none; margin: 0 auto; width: 768px; display:block;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a text-align:center; to the **parent** div and the width you want to have the image centered in (100% eg) removing the margin 0 auto

Answer (score 1):

`img` is inline tag so you need either change `display:block` and then `margin: 0 auto` or in parent tag put `text-align:center`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `flexbox` to your logo container.

```
#logo{
    width:800px;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/86n9qb7b/