# Inline element inside inline-block div

Tags: html, css

Can't get my head around on why `<img>` inside `<div style="display: inline-block">` pushes that `div` lower from top?

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="a1">
            <img src='...' alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div id="a2">
        </div>
        <div id="a3">
        </div>
        <div id="a4">
        </div>
        <div id="a5">
        </div>
        <div id="a6">
        </div>
        <div id="a7">
        </div>
        <div id="a8">
        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div > div {
    background: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 19%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 5% 5% 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

img {
    height: 128px;
    width: 128px;
    display: /* "BLOCK" FIXES THE ISSUE */; 
}
```

**EDIT**

Setting `img` to `display: block` fixes the issue. But could anyone explain me why there is such a behaviour without that `display: block`?

Comment: Just add ``vertical-align: top;`` to your ``div > div`` in your CSS file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) value is `baseline`, it can be the bottom line of the text or the bottom line of an image (`img` element is a [replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element), [inline* level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)), which causes the offset in the first row of your demo.

In order to fix it, you can set `vertical-align` to `top`, or like you said set `img` to `display: block` also works.

Answer (score 5):

The img tag behaves like a inline and bock element, basead on this answer: [Is <img> element block level or inline level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402761/is-img-element-block-level-or-inline-level)

That's why you have to display block on the img inside a div with inline-block.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by either adding a `float: left` or `vertical-align:top`

https://jsfiddle.net/foxhh0av/

```css
div > div {
 background: red;
 height: 200px;
 width: 19%;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 5% 5% 0;
 display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

img {
 height: 128px;
 width: 128px;
 display: /* "BLOCK" FIXES THE ISSUE */; 
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="a1">
   <img src='http://dfsm9194vna0o.cloudfront.net/1471693-0-Washingmachineforlaundry128.png' alt=""/>
  </div>
  <div id="a2">
  </div>
  <div id="a3">
  </div>
  <div id="a4">
  </div>

  <div id="a5">
  </div>
  <div id="a6">
  </div>
  <div id="a7">
  </div>
  <div id="a8">
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change this in your css:

```
img {
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  display: block; 
}
```

That should fix it.

Comment: Thank you. I've found that "block" fixes this. But could you please explain me, why there is such a behaviour without "display: block"?

Answer (score 1):

You could set `vertical-align: top;` to your child divs (div > div).

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain me why there is such a behaviour without that `v-a: top`?

Comment: The `vertical-align: top;` says that the top of the element is at the top of the parent-element. Example: The content of the child-divs has a different height, their top edge would be at the same height (default value is `baseline`).