# Vertical alignment works on block elements

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I was told that vertical-align only works for inline, and table elements, however, today I was playing around with vertical-align on a block element, it works just fine? How is that possible? In this case, does vertical-align work for all element types? Or if not, what doesn't it work on?

```css
#wrap {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
}
#alignTop {
vertical-align: top;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'wrap'>
<div id = 'alignTop'> alignTop </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Set it to `vertical-align: bottom` and you'll see it doesn't work. By default all element's start at the top.

Comment: @LGSon If there are 2 inline-elements, and if the first element has more height than the second element, the second element automatically goes to the bottom of the wrapper. Then if you use vertical-align top, on the second element, it goes back to the top.

Comment: Yes, it does, though it does not work on block level elements, like a `div`, which @dippas so nicely answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to explanations documented on [This](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/) link:

> - HTML layout traditionally was not designed to specify vertical behavior. By its very nature, it scales width-wise, and the content flows to an appropriate height based on the available width. Traditionally, horizontal sizing and layout is easy; vertical sizing and layout was derived from that.
> - `vertical-align` is used to specify two completely different behaviors depending on where it is used

## vertical-align in table cells

When used in table cells, `vertical-align` does what most people expect it to, which is mimic the (old, deprecated) `valign` attribute. In a modern, standards-compliant browser, the following three code snippets do the same thing:

1. `<td valign="middle"> <!-- but you shouldn't ever use valign --> </td>`
2. `<td style="vertical-align:middle"> ... </td>`
3. `<div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle"> ... </div>`

## vertical-align on inline elements

When `vertical-align` is applied to **inline** elements, however, it's a whole new ballgame. In this situation, it behaves like the (old, deprecated) `align` attribute did on `<img>` elements. In a modern, standards-compliant browser, the following three code snippets do the same thing:

1. `<img align="middle" ...>`
2. `<img style="vertical-align:middle" ...>`
3. `<span style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle"> foo<br>bar </span>`

Comment: So it only works for inline, table elements, and image elements?

Comment: Thats exactly true. You may not use it on a block-level element, except for those `inline-blocks` which mimic the inline behavior too

Comment: Aha! So it works for inline-blocks too! Now that's more clear. Cuz, I was messing around with inline-blocks and used vertical-alignment on one of the element and it worked, so I assumed that it works for block elements too.

Comment: @jessica img is a inline element, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402761/is-img-element-block-level-or-inline-level/2402781#2402781)

Comment: That is well answered here on [Is <img> element block level or inline level?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402761/is-img-element-block-level-or-inline-level)

Comment: " When the novice developer applies vertical-align to normal block elements (like a standard <div>) most browsers set the value to inherit to all inline children of that element." - No they don't. Vertical-align doesn't inherit by default. They don't now, and they didn't in 2004 when that article was written.

Answer (score 2):

By default `block` element stack on top of each other, so it **DOESN'T** work.

See [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#normal-flow)

> In a block formatting context, boxes are laid out one after the other,
>   vertically, beginning at the top of a containing block. The vertical
>   distance between two sibling boxes is determined by the 'margin'
>   properties. Vertical margins between adjacent block-level boxes in a
>   block formatting context collapse.

And you can see on [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) that `vertical-align` doesn't work in `block` elements, only applies to `inline-level` and `table-cell`

> ```
> Value:    baseline | sub | super | top | text-top | middle | bottom | text-bottom | <percentage> | <length> | inherit
> Initial:      baseline
> Applies to:   inline-level and 'table-cell' elements
> Inherited:    no
> Percentages:      refer to the 'line-height' of the element itself
> Media:    visual
> Computed value:   for <percentage> and <length> the absolute length, otherwise as specified
> ```

#### Snippet

```css
#wrap {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
#alignTop {
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#alignMiddle {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#alignBottom {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrap'>
  <div id='alignBottom'>alignBottom</div>
  <div id='alignTop'>alignTop</div>
  <div id='alignMiddle'>alignMiddle</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "see on W3C that that vertical-align ... only applies to inline-block and table-cell" . No it only applies to inline-**level** and table-cell elements. That includes inline, inline-block, inline-table, and inline-flex.