# What is causing the extra padding?

Tags: css, html

I've got 2 section tags on top of each other. The first contains an image the second just some text.

But for some reason the first is putting a few pixels extra padding at the bottom.
Why????

```
<section class="s1"><img src="something.jpg" width="500" height="500" /></section>
<section class="s2"> Test Test Test </section>
```

I tried this in the styling

```
section, img {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}
.s1 {
    background-color: black
}
.s2 {
    background-color: red
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ctscby6z/

Ignore the fact it's a broken image, does the same with a real image too.

Thanks.

Comment: Wow, 4 `display: block` answers. I prefer `vertical-align: top`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `img` is *inline* element. So make `display: block` for it.

Comment: Our replies are a couple of seconds apart! Has it always been this way? I thought `img` was block by default all this time...

Comment: OMG.... How thick am I :) Thanks for that.

Comment: @Tek Some browsers render `img` as `inline-block` element, some as `inline`.

Comment: @AlexM I haven't found any browser which renders images as `inline-block`s by default. Anyways, `inline-block` replaced elements should behave basically like `inline` replaced elements, so it doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 1):

At a glance this happens when display types are different.

`display: block;` fixes this.

Comment: Thanks for the response Tek. Like you I assumed img where block by default.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `display: block;` to image: https://jsfiddle.net/Mindaugas/jk4yyw48/1/

Comment: Thanks for the response Mindaugas.

Answer (score 1):

`<img>` tags by default are displayed as [inline block elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2402773/557445), however in an instance like this, you would want to use `display:block;` instead :

```
img { display: block }
```

**Example**

[image]

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
section,
img {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
.s1 {
  background-color: black
}
.s2 {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<section class="s1">
  <img src="something.jpg" width="500" height="500" />
</section>
<section class="s2">Test Test Test</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Rion.