# Image is not centered even margin auto applied

Tags: html, css, margin, margins

Trying to move the picture to the centre of the page using CSS. I applied these values to the image, but no success. See code below:

HTML:

```
<div class="list_of_reviews">
<ul style="list-style-type:none">
<li>What will happen to Brittish travelers when Brexit finaly happens</li>
</ul>
</div>
<img class="image_1" src="for left column.jpg" alt="What will happen to Brittish travelers when Brexit finaly happens"/>
```

CSS:

```
.list_of_reviews {
    margin:80px auto;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, Serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 40%;     
    border:solid;
}


.image_1 {
    margin:auto;
    height:200px;
    width:350px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Would really appreciate straight to the point answer and no downgrading please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `margin: 0 auto` to work you need to add `display: block`.

```css
.list_of_reviews {
  margin: 80px auto;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, Serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 40%;
  border: solid;
}
.image_1 {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 350px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="list_of_reviews">
  <ul style="list-style-type:none">
    <li>What will happen to Brittish travelers when Brexit finaly happens</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<img class="image_1" src="http://placehold.it/350x200" alt="What will happen to Brittish travelers when Brexit finaly happens" />
```

---

**EDIT:**

Actually...

> Don't change the default behavior of an element if you can avoid it.
>   Keep elements in the natural document flow as much as you can.

---

Since images behave like text by default, it is better if you do this:

```css
.list_of_reviews {
  margin: 80px auto;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, Serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 40%;
  border: solid;
}
figure {
  text-align: center;
}
.image_1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 350px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="list_of_reviews">
  <ul style="list-style-type:none">
    <li>What will happen to Brittish travelers when Brexit finaly happens</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<figure>
  <img class="image_1" src="for left column.jpg" alt="What will happen to Brittish travelers when Brexit finaly happens" />
</figure>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default `<img>` are set to `display: inline;` (although they technically have certain `display: inline-block;` properties - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2402773/3997209.

You can override that to `display: block;` quite easily and your required layout will work: https://jsfiddle.net/er13qobj/

Answer (score 0):

Instead I would recommend this way however it finds silly but still it works,

```
<div class="list_of_reviews">
<ul style="list-style-type:none">
<li>What will happen to Brittish travelers when Brexit finaly happens</li>
</ul>
</div>
<center>
<img src="for left column.jpg" alt="What will happen to Brittish travelers when Brexit finaly happens"/>
</center>
```