# Why does width/height work on an inline img element

Tags: css

It is my understanding that inline elements can't usually be sized using CSS `width` and `height` properties. It seems that an inline `img` is an exception to this, and that you can resize it using `width` and `height`.

```
img {
  display: inline;
  height: 35px; // this works
}
```

I'd like to understand if this is something specialized to an `img` tag, or if there is some other nuance that makes this work.

Can someone point me towards some spec or documentation that describes this behavior?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402761/is-img-element-block-level-or-inline-level

Comment: if it is deformed.. you can add     width: auto;

Comment: That is because the images are resizable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

an `img` is an inline **replaced** element unlike `span` for example which is an inline **non-replaced** element and we can define width/height on replaced element. Here is the relevant part of the specification that define how height/width should behave

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-height

When it comes to **non-replaced** elements you will find this:

> The 'width' property does not apply. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-width)</sup>
>
> The 'height' property does not apply. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced)</sup>

---

Same logic apply to tranformation where we can apply transformation to `img` and not `span`.

Related: [CSS transform doesn't work on inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14883250/8620333)

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#replaced-elements

---

Note that in [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inlineblock-replaced-width) it's also said that inline-block replaced element are exactly the same as inline replaced element so setting `inline` or `inline-block` to the img  will make no difference.