# CSS width for inline vs. inline-block

Tags: html, css, width, inline

I am trying to understand how the "width" style affects a "display: inline" vs. "display: inline-block" element. The key here is understanding, not trying to achieve a specific effect.

My previous understanding was that a "display: inline" element has an intrinsic width (from its contents) that cannot be overriden by a CSS "width" style -- any such style will be ignored. In contrast, a "display: inline-block" element has its width either determined from the context (surrounding block element) or its "width" style, ignoring the intrinsic width of its contents and instead using that outer width to break its contents into lines.

However, that understanding does not seem to match reality. Instead, it seems like "inline" behaves exactly like "inline-block". Example:

```
<p>
foo <input type="text" name="foo" style="display: inline; width: 500px; appearance: none"> baz
</p>
```

The "foo" and "bar" strings show the size of the input element as seen from the outside, just in case it differs from its border, but that isn't the case here. The input is set to display:inline, and I confirmed this in the "computed styles" tab in Chrome just to rule out any typo. I would have expected the input to have a width that is intrinsic and comes from its contents, growing as you type text into it. However, this is not the case -- typing text does not change the width, and typing text longer than the input makes the text get clipped at the left side, similar to what one would expect from a display:inline-block element with an appropriate "overflow" style.

Also, the "width" style determines the width of the input, which is unexpected given its display:inline. A quick google search reveals many sources that claim that "width" does not affect a display:inline element, yet it seems that this is exactly what happens.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Interesting. This seems to happen with input in particular; elements such as a, p or div behave "as they should". In practice, it seems as if input displays as inline-block instead when you set it to inline, even if the browser reports otherwise. But I haven't found any mention of this being the case.

Comment: There is a special category of elements that are called "replaced elements" - their content does not actually result from the HTML code itself, but comes from elsewhere. And those behave differently, in terms of whether width and height apply, when they are technically "inline". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element

Comment: _"I would have expected the input to have a width that is intrinsic and comes from its contents, growing as you type text into it."_ - if that was the case, then pure HTML forms without additional formatting besides what comes from the UA stylesheet, would behave terribly "jittery", no one can _want_ such a behavior as the default.

Comment: CBroe: That article says that text inputs are not replaced elements: "However, other form controls, including other types of <input> elements, are explicitly listed as non-replaced elements" ("other" meaning other than type "image"). But even if they were replaced elements, that would not explain why the "width" style changes its width.

Comment: Re: Jittery forms, why would that happen? The UA stylesheet sets text inputs to display:inline-block by default, which seems like a sensible default to me and would also prevent the problem you describe from happening. I'm not at all arguing that display:inline is a sensible default for text inputs, but rather asking why they behave like they do (and not become "jittery") when set to display:inline. It seems like the "width comes from content" rule only applies to *some* display:inline elements, but that raises the questions why and which elements those are.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55358531/8620333

Answer (score 0):

`input` elements behave like `inline-block`, even if you set `display: inline`.

```html
<p>
foo <span style="display: inline; width: 300px; background: pink;">inline</span> bar
</p>

<p>
foo <span style="display: inline-block; width: 300px; background: pink;">inline-block</span> bar
</p>

<p>
foo <input type="text" name="foo" style="display: inline; width: 300px; background: pink;" value="inline"> bar
</p>

<p>
foo <input type="text" name="foo" style="display: inline-block; width: 300px; background: pink;" value="inline-block"> bar
</p>
```

Comment: Do you know a part in the specs, browser docs, MDN oder similar that describe this? Which other elements behave like this? Why does input do this and in what other ways does it differ from other elements?

Comment: @MartinGeisse - This is described in the rendering section of the HTML living standard and is common to form elements. In early browsers, form elements were provided by calls to the O/S - They were _replaced_ by the O/S. For backward compatibility, they still behave similar to replaced elements even though they are now implemented  directly by the browser. The closest CSS display type to an inline replaced element is inline-block.