# Why is wrapping image with <a href> link changing the layout of the page?

Tags: html, css

Adding < a href> to images makes the box around the image larger and forces the text on the right hand side of the image further right. I would like to make the image link to another page while keeping the current format.

I tried adding  to the image (alt is connector) (shown below), but it didn't work. (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp - Image as a Link
 uses  around ).

I would expect adding the  to the image would simply make the image link to another page, but it changed the size of the box for the image and pushed the text to the right of the image further right.

Page: https://www.flexsweep.com/pages/aboutourproducts (shows layout as it should be - provides access to inspect if needed.)

```css
/*Image and Advantages*/

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.content img {
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 70px;
}

.details {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="PushBrooms" class="tabcontent">

  <p>Intro text.</p>

  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2355/6001/files/BlackConnector.PushBroom.White.Smooth.jpg?765" alt="Connector" />

    <div class="details">
      <p>
        More text.
        <div><a href="https://www.flexsweep.com/collections/unbreakable-push-brooms" class="buttonLink buttonShop">Shop Push Brooms →</a></div>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Attempt to add link to image -->

  <a href="www.flexsweep.com"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2355/6001/files/BlackConnector.PushBroom.White.Smooth.jpg?765" alt="Connector" /></a>
```

Comment: What's "alt=connector" supposed to do? What are we supposed to be seeing in the link you posted?

Comment: Why have you tried to fix your problem giving the `<img>` `alt="connector"`? Could you please link any documentation stating it might be the proper solution?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it do what you are trying to do

Comment: The `alt` attribute was required in HTML4 and [it's still recommended to define it](https://www.joedolson.com/2015/03/are-alt-attributes-required-always/) for those users using a screen reader. I assume that's why the author of the question added it to avoid misbehavior due to incomplete attributes.

Comment: Your snippet does not place an anchor tag around the image, so we can't see whatever it is that you're having trouble with.  I'd guess that there is other CSS on the page that is affecting links, or else relative styling that's being affected by the lack of the img tag where it originally was.

Comment: @RutherfordWonkington I thought that as well but in fact there is a larger version of the image in the bottom part below that is contained in an anchor tag.

Comment: I originally built the page without adding the link to the images (I think that is the anchor tag - I am learning as I go here). I then realized that the images should go to the same link as the buttons, but when I added the link, it changed the layout. Adding links to text in the intro text paragraph and shop button worked just fine.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<p>` element cannot contain a `<div>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original image is sized at 50% width from the CSS rule on `.content img`.  This only affects img tags that are descendants of elements with the `content` class.  If you apply `content` to the link, it will work as you expect.

Edit: Noticed this will not work if you place it inside all inside another `content` container because the relative width is calculated from the parent, which in the second case will be the `a` element and not the `content` div.  I updated the snippet to size descendant links of content to be sized at 50% width and the contained images to be 100%.

To address the small amount of padding at the bottom of the link, you can use the solution provided in Sascha's answer

```css
/*Image and Advantages*/

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.content img {
  width: 50%;
}

.link-wrap {
  width: 50%;
}

.link-wrap img {
  width: 100%;
}



.details {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="PushBrooms" class="tabcontent">

  <p>Intro text.</p>

  <div class="content">
    <img  src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2355/6001/files/BlackConnector.PushBroom.White.Smooth.jpg?765" alt="Connector" />

    <div class="details">
      <p>
        More text. </p>
        <div><a href="https://www.flexsweep.com/collections/unbreakable-push-brooms" class="buttonLink buttonShop">Shop Push Brooms →</a></div>
     
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Attempt to add link to image -->


  
    <div class="content">
      <a class="link-wrap" href="www.flexsweep.com"><img  src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2355/6001/files/BlackConnector.PushBroom.White.Smooth.jpg?765" alt="Connector" /></a>

    <div class="details">
      <p>
        More text.</p>
        <div><a href="https://www.flexsweep.com/collections/unbreakable-push-brooms" class="buttonLink buttonShop">Shop Push Brooms →</a></div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried adding the class="content", but it pushed the text below the image.

Comment: Your answer plays with the same invalid HTML the OP uses.

Comment: You mean the div in the p tag in the details section?  Honestly I didn't take a close look at that, but the image/link tags should be OK unless I missed something.

Comment: I don't know. I would never work with, or answer questions of, any markup or code that contains fundamental errors.

Comment: Something about this made my code unhappy (all of a sudden all red when normally black) and hid the image. My guess is that there is something small somewhere that is preventing this from acting as expected since there is no obvious solution.

Comment: You can't place a div inside of a paragraph tag as it will break the text flow.  To address it you just have to move the closing p tag back to the end of the text.  I fixed it in my snippet.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! 

The padding was a bit off, but I can work on that.

Comment: I switched the div and p and it didn't affect the layout or this solution. I will fix the rest of them though to make the code better.

Comment: To address the small amount of padding at the bottom of the link, you can use the solution provided in [Sascha's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1178759/sascham78) answer.

Answer (score 4):

`IMG` tags behave special as they are a mixture of "block" (have height and width) and "inline" (float around text) elements. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402761/is-img-element-block-level-or-inline-level) some good information about this topic if you want to learn more about it.

Images in `<a>` tags have an extra bit of padding at the footer which you can get rid of by applying `display:block;` to the element. Also make sure that there is no extra margin or padding applied by some other rules:

```
a img {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/wuL4bv2r/) with some colored backgrounds to show you which element applies padding or margin.