# Why is css text-align:center, not centering text? Underlining in the same format is working

Tags: css, text-alignment, text-align

I wrote simple CSS to align text using the w3schools example with:

```
text-align:center
```

When I add an underline in the same format, the underline works.

Here's the snippet:

```css
.CenterIt {
 text-align:center;
}
.UnderlineIt {
 text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<span class="UnderlineIt">
<span class="CenterIt">Registration Form</span>
</span>
```

Here's the w3schools page (the align text section):
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

In my full code I have the text I want to center inside another box. I've tried it both inside that box and outside any boxes. It doesn't center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.CenterIt {
 text-align:center;
  display:block;
}
.UnderlineIt {
 text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<span class="UnderlineIt">
<span class="CenterIt">Registration Form</span>
</span>
```

The display property of `span` by default is `inline`. i.e.,

```
display:inline;
```

Therefore, `<span>` will take only the width of its content. In contrast, `block` elements like `<div>`, by default, take the full line (and thereby the full width of the page) for its content.

To make the text-align work for `<span>`, you need to change it into a `block` element.

Set

`display: block;`

for the `span` with `.CenterIt` class. This will make `.CenterIt` take the full line (and thereby the full width of the page), and then the `text-align: center;` will centralize the content.

Comment: This also gave me enough understanding to fix a problem where I couldn't get an image picture to fill a box I'd created. I need to put the class onto the img tag, not on a box around it!

Comment: @curls. Glad to help. BTW, <img> is a replaced inline element. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402761/is-img-element-block-level-or-inline-level

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You need to wrap it with a container unit of `<div>`

```
<div class="UnderlineIt">
    <div class="CenterIt">Registration Form</div>
</div>
```

Following will work as well

```
<span class="UnderlineIt">
    <div class="CenterIt">Registration Form</div>
</span>
```

Comment: That did it. It can't center within a span I suppose. But can center in a div. That makes sense. I hadn't thought of it at all. Thanks!

Comment: The 3wschools, could add that centering needs a box or div... that would have been helpful there!

Answer (score 1):

It might work better if you run “display: flex;” on the container span and “justify-content: center;” on the child span. Flexbox is a little easier to use when placing items within a container.

Comment: Never heard of display:flex. I'll have to look it up!

Answer (score 1):

Because your html, is in wrong format. You cant have a span child of a span.

try like this:

```html
<div class="CenterIt">
<span class="UnderlineIt">Registration Form</span>
</div>
```

to have the span centered , without a parent div you would need to put the display, as block.
so you could have on your html and css like this:

```
span{display:block;}


 .CenterIt {
    text-align:center;
}
.UnderlineIt {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

html:

```
<span class="UnderlineIt CenterIt">Registration Form</span>
```

Comment: You can have a span inside a span with other tags. I've had it work. But the center needs something to center to, so that makes sense that a div outside it is needed!

I haven't used blocks. That's interesting for me to look up and understand better.

Comment: yes , you can do whatever you want,, but I think isnt semantic HTML.