# Behavior of img width when max-width is set

Tags: css, image, flexbox

I have a list (ul) where each item (li) contains an icon and a text span. This list is nested within a  container, which may not have sufficient width to accommodate it. here is the code

```css
* {
  border: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.list-container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 24px;
  list-style:none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.list-container li {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-top: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon {
  background: green;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-right: 14px;
}

.list-container li:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="list-container">
      <li>
        <img class="icon" src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/favicon.png" />
        <span>Hello World !!!</span></li>
      <li>
        <div class="icon"></div><span>JavaScript</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <span>Rust</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the width of the 'div' container is narrower than the 'ul', an odd behavior occurs. When the icon is an 'img' with a max-width of 100%, the text within the span extends beyond the bounds of the 'li'. However, if the 'img' lacks a max-width setting or is substituted with a 'div', the 'li' successfully accommodates the full width of both the icon and the span. The result can be checked here (https://jsfiddle.net/c508dz6o/1/)

I understand that I could achieve the same result using a custom list marker or other ways. However, I'm really interested in understanding the CSS rules that are causing this behavior with the image's max-width. Can anyone help me figure that out?

Comment: Hi! I got it. The `.container` had no explicit `width`. Thereby the `max-width:100%` of the `li` had no use. `100%` of  w h a t? https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/hq39gu0L/ 

Comment: @deEr. the .container is set to a width of 50px. I'm just wondering why there's a difference in behavior despite both the img and div being block-level elements.

Comment: Just remove the max-width and just keep width:16px; in your .icon and they will behave the same (no overflow). Your fiddle image initial size is set to 32px

Comment: `img` is inline-level-element. `div` is block-level-element. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2402773/2569323 

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the max-width and just keep width:16px; in your .icon and they will behave the same (no overflow). Remember Your fiddle image initial size is set to 32px

```css
* {
  border: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.list-container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 24px;
  list-style:none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.list-container li {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-top: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon {
  background: green;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-right: 14px;
}

.list-container li:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="root">
        <div class="container">
          <ul class="list-container">
            <li>
              <img class="icon" src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/favicon.png"/>
              <span>Hello World !!!</span></li>
            <li>
              <div class="icon"></div><span>JavaScript</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="icon"></div>
              <span>Rust</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```